# Difference between Ubuntu scheme and XWin Scheme

Tags: ubuntu, constructor, cygwin, scheme, selector

I am learning 61a from UCB using MITScheme.

For the first few chapters, I have been using windows (First download cygwin, then run XWin type emacs & and I get my emacs editor and REPL).

This has worked fine but I have switched to Ubuntu and I am using MIT Scheme.  It has been working well but I recently ran into a problem.

[I am using Release 9.1 of MIT/GNU Scheme on Ubuntu and STk Interperter version 4.0.1 on Windows]

I am trying to write a black jack program.

I take the input as a hand of cards '(ad 8s 5h) [for ace diamond, 8 spades, 5 hearts].

To access the 'a value, the UCB lectures and the windows version are fine with:

(first (first '(ad 8s 5h))) ===> a

When I try this on Ubuntu MIT Scheme, I get the error:

The object ad, passed as an argument to safe-car, is not a pair.

After some testing I see that MIT scheme here will use first to extract the first item of a list:

(first '(ad 8s 5h)) =====> ad

But it will not use first as a selector for the first letter of a single word.

Can anybody give me a suggestion?  I would like to keep learning this course on Ubuntu because it makes my life much easier in terms of saving and opening files for example.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Remember that you have not just one scheme implementation available in Software Center but more than a dozen. In addition to `MIT Scheme` (R5RS) you have:  `DrRacket`, `Ikarus`, `Gambit`, `Chicken`, `Scm`, `Scheme48`, `Sigscheme`, `Sisc` (uses JRE), `Tinyscheme`, `Scsh`, `Gauche`, `Elk`, `Scheme9`, `Stalin`, `Scheme2c` and `Oaklisp`. The two first in the list supports the latest standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `first` for accessing the first character in a symbol is not portable across Scheme implementations. In most interpreters `first` or `car` will *only* work for pairs. To access the first character in a symbol create a helper procedure:

```
(define (first-symbol sym)
  (string->symbol               ; 4. convert the string to a symbol
   (string                      ; 3. create a one-character string
    (string-ref                 ; 2. get the first character in the string
     (symbol->string sym) 0)))) ; 1. convert the symbol to a string
```

The above function uses only standard procedures, it should work fine in any RxRS interpreter. Use it like this:

```
(first-symbol (first '(ad 8s 5h)))
=> 'a
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Oscar Lopez!

Comment: I found out my problem:  On windows I am using STk version of Scheme, which differs from MIT Scheme.  I had to install STk and configure my .emacs to run stk-stimply instead of mit-scheme when I (MX run-scheme) in EMACS!